# In-memory/Embedded DB solution

Tags: sqlite, embedded-database, in-memory-database

I'm currently using the in-memory option for SQLite and while it works (a bit slow right now but I'm still exploring ways to optimize my usage of it like batching and such), I'm just curious whether there are other alternatives to SQLite that support in-memory DBs and are embedded solutions.  I don't necessarily need a schema-based DB (NoSQL would be an interesting thing to try).  I do writes more frequently than reads (this is part of a backend for a web application), so I need my updates to be fast enough to keep up with the incoming flow of data.

I believe SQLite is probably more than capable of handling the volume with some optimizations on the query-side, but I'm just wondering about the alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried Oracle's [TimesTen](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/timesten/index.html) database? (Wikipedia article available [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TimesTen))

Comment: I would prefer if there is an open source solution, but I'll check it out.